# Get value from external spreadsheet on sharepoint office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, sharepoint

I have two excel spreadsheets on SharePoint office 365.  Ho/can I access one spreadsheet from the other?

E.g. if I had one spreadsheet called “sales” and the other called “inventory” and I wanted to query the sales spreadsheet to update “quantity sold” on inventory, how would I do this?

It would be like saying =Sheet1!C6 except Sheet1 is on another spreadsheet in SharePoint.  Would it be under Data>New Query or Data>Get External Data or something else?

Also would it update automatically, or would I have to use the refresh connections button in excel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can since SharePoint Online doesn't give you access to Excel Services which is what you need.

If you are able to convert the spreadsheets to Lists you could do it. You would have been able to use Access Web as well but Microsoft are in the process of turning it off.

Annoyingly, Excel uses absolute file references when linking between workbooks and there is no mechanism for doing that in SharePoint directly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a way to do this in access?

Comment: Yes, Access will read spreadsheets but you asked for O365. You can do what you want purely in Excel of course.